# How do I fetch the contents of a page no matter what HTTP status code?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm currently using `file_get_contents()` to fetch the contents of a page which is sort of like an Authentication API. It works great for the default system which most people use (which just uses the default HTTP/1.1 200 status code), but some people send relevant HTTP status codes for different errors. For example 401 PASSWORD_FAIL, in which case it would set the HTTP status to 401 and output 'PASSWORD_FAIL' to the page, which is the part I want to get. But the 401 status code causes `file_get_contents()` to error out and not do anything. What is the simplest PHP function I can use to get the contents of the page and just ignore the HTTP status code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'ignore_errors'  => true,
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

See the manual on the [http wrapper context options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use function stribet.

```
function stribet($inputstr, $deliLeft, $deliRight) {
    $posLeft = stripos($inputstr, $deliLeft) + strlen($deliLeft);
    $posRight = stripos($inputstr, $deliRight, $posLeft);
    return substr($inputstr, $posLeft, $posRight - $posLeft);
}
```

$res = file_get_contents("web page");
$test=@$this->stribet($res,'`<html>`','`</html>`');

for more info check [PHP.Net stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)